# How to setup disk encryption + periodic backup (SSD -> HDD -> Cloud) on a dual-boot environment?

Tags: backup, multi-boot, disk-encryption, cloud-storage

super users! I have this Dell laptop with 1TB SSD (half Windows 10 and half Ubuntu 21.04), GPT partitions and EFI boot. I also have a 1TB HDD installed on the laptop that I intend to use only to backup the data on my SSD.

I need some high-level guidance on how to do the setup, please. I'd like to enable encryption on the SSD, then periodically trigger the backup to HDD (e.g. every week, or whenever I shutdown the laptop). Ideally, my backup should be able to restore both systems including boot, so if the laptop explodes (or ransomware attack etc.) I can still buy a new one and recover everything like nothing had happened (it's OK to lose some days of data). That implies I need to periodically upload backup data to a cloud storage.

That's the use case, but I don't know how to enable the encryption and what software(s) would allow me to do that. Do any of you have a similar setup? How can I achieve that? I'm open to any suggestions, the only hard requirement is the encryption part, so a simple cloud-sync tool like google drive client is not enough.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some general statements to a **very** broad question.

There are many encryption schemes, some OS-dependent, some relying on hardware, [such as TPM](https://tpm2-software.github.io/2020/04/13/Disk-Encryption.html), some performed by software such as [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/code/VeraCrypt/). You might [research encryption standards](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-111/final), and decide what level of security is needed and what competencies are required for its implementation.

That said, some notes on "backup", i.e., disk imaging in the case of an encrypted drive.

1. If you encrypt the whole disk, make frequent *whole disk images*.
2. **Verify** that you can *open* and *browse* that encrypted backup. If you can, restore an image to another HDD and **confirm that your password works from that drive**. [An employer for whom I worked zealously backed up all machines daily... only to find that none were usable when needed.]
3. There are many excellent disk imaging applications that can schedule backups.

   - For *Windows*, try [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) or [others](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/). Windows has the [Volume Shadow Copy Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/volume-shadow-copy-service), which takes a self-consistent snapshot of a partition, allowing for imaging a drive while it's in use (not exactly optimal, however).
   - Mac OS apparently also has [tools to schedule disk imaging](https://www.techpout.com/best-disk-cloning-apps-for-mac/),though I don't know if any can be run while the disk is mounted. [Comments are welcome!]
   - Linux, AFAIK, requires the drive being imaged to be unmounted, [though check the utilities for more information](https://www.ubuntupit.com/best-backup-software-for-linux/). Scheduling an image while the machine is in use is problematical. [Again, comments/corrections are appreciated.]
   - In *any* case, a full disk image made by one OS can restore *all* partitions, so you only need effective backup/restore tools for one OS.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of guidance I need, thank you! Now I'll do the research :)